# rails 4 strong params: make them conditional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, conditional-statements, strong-parameters

**Is there a way to make strong_params conditional?** 
Without the need to write 2 separate methods? In case where one would like to add certain attributes to the permit list when a certain condition is true

For example:

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) {|u| u.permit(:user,
                                                    :email,
                                                    :role,
                                                    )}
```

I have this :role attribute permitted in above example. I only want this attribute to be permitted when in Rails.env.development is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't found a solution, so I made 2 methods and call the correct param method to handle the records.

Answer (score 10):

Does this achieve the desired results?

```
user_params = [ :user, :email, (:role if Rails.env.development?) ].compact
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:user) { |u| u.permit(*user_params) }
```

Comment: My apologies, just saw the answered on date. This question is quite old.

Comment: Old or not, the answer you gave is a valid and useful one.  Just need to wrap my head around the syntax a bit, but I think that I, at least, will be using it!