# Ruby on Rails:Remove some elements in Strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Examples: i have 4 check boxes for boolean values which correspond to 4 texts : A,B,C,D. 
I need to push texts which is checked ( = true ).[image: Example] 
But in default,Strong Parameters will get all values from our form to save into database, but i need only push one of them , not all. So i need to remove all text which isn't checked in Strong Parameters . How can i do it ??
I know that after Strong Parameters is permitted , we can not change anything inside it.
My strong parameters in controller:

```
params.require(:question).permit(:id, :job_id, :content,answers_attributes: [ :id, :content,:result ])
```

(Answers is nested atribute)

Comment: You can try conditional permit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536672/rails-4-strong-params-make-them-conditional

Comment: I guess you are using it for an update action, if not you can remove the `:id`. But if you want update the questions and its answers, once a result is true it can't be changed to false (because false values were filtered).